# Transformar un foreach a un java-stream para validar un boolean

Tags: java, java-stream

Hola comunidad buenas tardes. Tengo una duda con manejo de stream en java, actualmente tengo una lista de Objetos donde el objeto tiene un atributo booleano, requiero saber si de todos los objetos en la lista existe algún Objeto cuyo atributo booleano se igual a `true`; para determinar esto estoy utilizando un `foreach` sobre la lista de objetos valido el atributo y si es igual a true hago un `break` para salirme del `for` ya que con el hecho de que exista uno es suficiente.

```
public class Object{
  private String texto;
  private boolean indicador;

  // getters y Setters
}
```

Y el método que uso es

```
public boolean metodo(List<Object> objetos){
  for(Object o : objetos){
    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(o.getIndicador())) {
      existeAlgunoVerdadero = Boolean.TRUE;
      break;
    }
  }
  return existeAlgunoVerdadero;
}
```

Ahora mi cuestión si esta forma de hacerlo se puede hacer con `stream`, he intentado hacer

```
objetos.stream().filter(o -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(o.getIndicador()))
```

Pero no se como capturar el valor y retornarlo en el método

Comment: En vez de toquetear con `filter` puedes ir a la [documentación oficial de Java para `Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) y ver si hay algún método que te pueda hacer eso... como en este caso, el `anyMatch` que devuelve `true` si alguno de los elementos cumple la condición especificada. `filter()` lo que hace es permitir que *pasen* los elementos que cumplen el filtro, pero no te devuelve un booleano como `anyMatch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
objetos.stream().filter(o -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(o.getIndicador()))
```

En este caso, usaría *findAny()*

```
Optional<Object> resultado = objetos.stream().filter(o -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(o.getIndicador())).findAny();
return resultado.isPresent();
```

`resultado` nunca será *null*, pero `isPresent()` solo será verdadero cuando se haya recuperado algún elemento del stream (en esencia, que no se hayan eliminado todos).

Para cosas más complicadas, puedes usar *reduce()* pasándole como operador la función a aplicar, o hacer un *collect* a una colección y trabajar sobre ella.

**Actualización** La sugerencia de Benito-B es más elegante, desde luego:

```
return objetos.stream().anyMatch(o -> Boolean.TRUE.equals(o.getIndicador()))
```

Comment: Si solo le interesa el `boolean`, si, mi solución es más elegante. Si le interesa *poder trabajar con el objeto indicado*, desde luego tu solución evitará abrir un segundo stream además de poder comprobar si existe o no de manera *rápida*, y al igual que con `anyMatch`, `findAny` tampoco evalúa **todo** el stream, pues en cuanto un elemento cumple la condición deja de evaluar los demás. Buena respuesta :)